# Storing original form values for later comparison, object or hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am about to rewrite a script I wrote a few years ago that checks a form for any changes in order to display a message like 'Would you like to save your changes?'...

My question is, quite simply, should I store the original values in a hidden form field, or a Javascript object? Which method is more efficient?

Here is an example of using the hidden field method:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="John Smith" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name_old" id="first_name_old" value="John Smith" />
```

And the javascript object alternative:

```
var old_values = {
    'first_name': 'John Smith'
}
```

Comment: Storing values "natively" (i.e. in a variable) will always be faster than involving the DOM in any way. Question is whether you will *notice* any difference.

Comment: I'd recoment storing values in similarly named hidden attributes and writing a generic function that would compare the two values. This way, you can add and remove form elements without changing comparison logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing values in JavaScript object is more transparent and maintainable, but means more structuring of the code instead of storing in a hidden field or data attribute.
If You are building a bigger frontend application storing all kind of values in the HTML can quickly become a mess, with lots of calls to modify the DOM.

If effective means speed, You should make a benchmark, which one is faster. But if You dont update the value that often this micro-optimalisation is negligible to the fact it makes the code less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as a [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attribute for same element.

### Edit

Sorry for misunderstanding, you can store it like this

`<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="John Smith" data-old_value="John Smith" />`

then

```
$('#first_name').data('old_value');
```

will give you the old value

Comment: For which ***same*** element?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to ensure is that I am using the most efficient method. So what i would like to know, should I store the value in javascript (regardless how I do it), or in the HTML?

Comment: I guess the OP is talking about a set of form elements not about a single element only.

Comment: so cant you use `data` for all the form elements?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Your text does not answer the question though. You should tell which way is preferable: using data or hidden field, but not how to use `data` for that.